# eslint rule for multiple conditionals

Tags: eslint

Is there an eslint rule that enforces newlines on multiple conditionals for **if statements**?

For example,

```
if (
    foo &&
    bar &&
    baz
) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get to enforce newlines: `/*eslint operator-linebreak: ["error", "after"]*/`.

```
if (someCondition 
  || otherCondition) {
}
```

Conditional will throw eslint error, and this will not:

```
if (someCondition ||
  otherCondition) {
}
```

[Eslint Prettier plugin](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier) may help you aswell with formatting, i am using this myself.

Comment: I get the impression that prettier does not allow for much customization.  The options i see [in the docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) seem limited and the lib itself determines most of what is "pretty".  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are! Prettier is opinionated and gives no much room for customization, though built in rules are 'pretty'   fine.